# Conditional Formatting Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have an average value for Agents(A) and I want to color this value regarding to another average value(B).
If A decreased by 15% from B I will color the A cell with RED.

Can anyone help me with this formula please :)
Thanks, I appreciate it

Comment: You need to use a custom formula option when creatin your CF rule, referencing A and B cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=A1<=B1*0.85` as rule for conditional formatting in column A (starting row 1) with format red.

Answer (score 0):

A formula for conditional formatting must have `TRUE` or `FALSE` as a result, so you might try the following:

```
=IF(C3<0,65*C2,TRUE,FALSE)
```

I tried this for the values 1-5 and these are the results (Waar=TRUE and Onwaar=False):

[image]

Comment: Should your formula be =IF(C3<0.65*C2,TRUE,FALSE) or =IF(C3<0,65*C2;TRUE;FALSE) depending on your locale? Maybe also .85 if OP is looking for 15% decrease?

Comment: Actually it should be different references as well: column A and B. And TRUE and FALSE would already be boolean, so no need to mention them.